# Print multiple Vaadin Charts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, printing, vaadin, vaadin-charts

Vaadin Charts offers the user to export or print them:[image]

But how do I print multiple Vaadin Charts?
For example adding a Print Button which creates a HTML/PDF with all (e.g. 4 or more) Vaadin Charts of a specific Vaadin page and print this page.

Purpose: Create a printable verison of a Vaadin webpage with multiple Vaadin Charts.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Open a clean new page, where you'd only show those diagrams and programatically call the print function of your browser.
2. In such a case, you'd probably use a whole document with text and diagrams - for that you may on the server side convert your content into a document format, like PDF. You could a) view this PDF and request your browser to print it or b) let the user download this. Read this: https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-charts-export-from-browser-to-svg-and-pdf